# Determine shells of all users whether it is login or non login shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to get the shell of all the users currently logged in a linux machine, whether it is a login shell or a non login shell.
I know how to get this for my self, but how to do it for all the users logged in on the machine...

Comment: What is a "non-login shell"? Do you mean just the command they chose as their shell when logging in via, e.g. `ssh` (`ssh somehost zsh`)?

Comment: whenever the user logs in remotely using ssh, he is in login shell, otherwise he is in non-login shell.

Comment: What do you want to display in these cases: a) I log in using `ssh somehost zsh`, then run `bash` inside `zsh` and `python` inside `bash`? b) I log in using `ssh somehost nano /etc/fstab` c) I log in locally, my login session is `zsh`, in which I execute `bash`, in which I execute `python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see something about other users, I am assuming you have root privileges on this box. Otherwise your question is moot from the start.

If you have root, you can run `ps -ef|grep $USERNAME` and compare the process names to the shells in /etc/shells. Each user will have one under normal circumstances. But if someone is launching bash inside ksh or some other shell combination, that is another issue.

Or if you just want to know what is the default shell of the other users, this command can help:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '{print $7}'
```

Maybe, if you can tell us why it is important for you to know what shell each user is running, you can get better answers